# My iPhoto Library.photolibrary will not copy to iCloud, shows a cloud with a slash through it

Tags: icloud, photos.app

iPhoto Library.photolibrary file is 311GB (yes I still use and love iPhoto). Size shows on Disk but where shows iCloud, yet it is not visible on iCloud via other devices and shows cloud with slash so I know it hasn't copied to iCloud. iPhoto does pull up just fine, finds the library under documents folder.

Side note, it did show ineligible for a long time (after I moved it out of pictures folder to documents folder on iCloud). Now shows the 311GB (yeah) which is how I discovered I needed more iCloud storage so did that today (2TB) and expected to see the up arrow to show it moving to iCloud but it still sits with cloud with slash.  I tried to drag and drop but nothing.

My hard drive is failing and my backup is old (shame on me) so this is critical for me. I can't seem to make a copy of it where it is at to another physical hard drive either. It is almost as if it is in limbo between cloud and hard disk.

Help, I don't want to lose this file!

Comment: RE: "My hard drive is failing ... Help, I don't want to lose this file!!" -- Then you should immediately copy it to an external USB drive.

Comment: If you can _only_ use the cloud, and/or if time is of the essence, try DropBox or Google Drive instead of iCloud to store this important file. Making a temporary new account as a stopgap is trivial against losing all those photos.

Comment: First backup to local disk - however for photos to cloud you do not copy the file but use the Photos app - select iCloud Photos in Preferences

Answer (score 1):

To save a copy of your photos in iCloud, try this approach:

- Open Disk Utility and choose File > New Image > Blank Image

  - Name it appropriately and size it at least 311 GB (350 or 400 GB is probably better)
  - Choose APFS format
  - Choose "read/write disk image" format
  - Save it to a non-iCloud location
- In Finder, open the dmg file you've just created and copy your iPhoto Library into it
- "Eject" the Disk Image then move it into iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

Prequel:
If your drive is failing, immediately grab some type of local storage (SD card, thumb drive, external HDD/SSD) and back up the files that matter to you. If they *really, really* matter to you (and you are willing to spend money) turn off the machine and go to a professional ASAP.

---

iCloud Drive has a 50GB file size limit (see: https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201104 and [Which file types are "ineligible" for iCloud drive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297880/which-file-types-are-ineligible-for-icloud-drive/412798#412798))

A workaround would be to split the file into multiple parts (using dmgparts for example: [What are "dmgpart" files and what tools can create, merge, or manage them?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44786/what-are-dmgpart-files-and-what-tools-can-create-merge-or-manage-them)).